# .NET WPF WebBrowser Control: Insert HTML at ControlRange selection

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, webbrowser-control

I have a WebBrowser control that I am using to create an HTML editor, and I need to be able to insert a string of HTML at the current selection in the document.

Generally, I can do something like this to paste HTML at the current selection, if the selection is a text selection:

```
IHTMLSelectionObject selection = webBrowser.Document.DomDocument.selection;

// Assume that selection.type == "Text"
IHTMLTxtRange textRange = selection.createRange() as IHTMLTxtRange;

textRange.pasteHTML(myHtmlString);
```

However, if the current selection is a ControlRange selection, there doesn't seem to be any direct way to insert/paste HTML at that position.

For example:

```
// Assume that selection.type == "Control"
IHTMLControlRange ctrlRange = selection.createRange() as IHTMLControlRange;

// This throws an error, as IHTMLControlRange has no pasteHTML method
ctrlRange.pasteHTML(myHtmlString);
```

I know that I can use the HtmlElement.InsertAdjacentElement method to insert an element before or after another element, but that is very limiting, as sometimes I need to be able to insert raw HTML, rather than needing to create an HtmlElement object for it first.

Is there any way to be able to paste/insert an HTML string at the caret position, or over a ControlRange selection?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround for this problem, at least for my specific use case.

The IHTMLSelectionObject.createRange() method returns dynamic, but it will resolve to either an IHTMLTxtRange or an IHTMLControlRange, depending on what the selection type is.
If selection.type == "Text" or selection.type == "None", it returns an IHTMLTxtRange, and if selection.type == "Control", it returns an IHTMLControlRange.

The following statement works for empty selections and text selections:

```
DomDocument.selection.createRange().pasteHTML(myHtml);
```

However, in the case of pasting over a control selection, the above statement won't work by default because the createRange() method will return an IHTMLControlRange, which, as mentioned above, has no createRange() method. However, we would be wanting to overwrite the current selection with the new HTML anyway, so one could assume that it is safe to just clear the selection (delete it) and then paste the HTML at the newly empty selection.

**Solution**

Something like this should work for all types of selections:

```
// If we have a control selection, clear the selection
if (DomDocument.selection.type == "Control")
    DomDocument.selection.clear();

// Now it is no longer a control selection, but an empty text selection
DomDocument.selection.createRange().pasteHTML(myHtml);
```

This does feel a bit hacky, but it solves the problem for me.